# Describing a set using linear inequalities

Tags: geometry, linear-programming

I am having a hard time understanding the answer to the following exercise (which was taken from "Linear Optimization and Extensions: Problems and Solutions" by Padberg and Alevras).

[image: Exercise 2.2 from "Linear Optimization and Extensions: Problems and Solutions" by Padberg and Alevras]

My problem lies in the last sentence of the answer. 
I know that:

$$\left| {x_j^ +  - x_j^ - } \right| \le 1 \Leftrightarrow \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{ - 1 \le x_j^ +  - x_j^ -  \le 1}&{,{\rm{if}}\;x_j^ +  \ge x_j^ - }\\{ - 1 \le  - x_j^ +  + x_j^ -  \le 1}&{,{\rm{if}}\;x_j^ +  < x_j^ - }\end{array}} \right.$$

but I can't arrive at the last set and I can't even see why it's equivalent to the first one. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are projecting $Y:=(x_i^{+},x_i^{-})$ to $X:=x_i^{+}-x_i^{-}$. First you need to see that  if $Y$ satisfies the given inequalities then $X$ is going to satisfy $|x|<1$. On the other hand, you need to see that any number $|a|<1$ can be written as $a=a^{+}-a^{-}$ such that $a^{+}+a^{-}<1$, $a^{+}\geq0$, and $a^{-}\geq0$.

Notice they are only claiming one is the projection of the other.

Comment: I wasn't understanding what the author had done because I didn't know what a projection was. Basically, he recognizes that the first set is the projection of the last one, so it holds the inequality in a higher dimensional space, right?
Thanks for your time.